# How to avoid returning an object when the class of the returned value is not evident at function call?

Tags: java, methods, return-type

For a project I am working on, I have to retrieve some entries from a NoSQL database. The values may either be Strings or Doubles, however, at the time of calling the method that retrieves these values, I do not know what type of value the field contains.

For the sake of argument here is a minimal working example, which is of course oversimplified:

```
public class ReturnType {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "This is a string.";
        double d = 23.5;

        getValue(s);
        getValue(d);
    }

    private static Object getValue(Object obj) {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

I have thought about checking the class of the object that is returned by the function and casting the returned object to that class:

```
if (getValue(s).getClass() == String.class){
            String result = s;
        } else if (getValue(s).getClass() == double.class)
        {
            Double result = d;
        }
```

However, I do not like this solution at all, as I have to hardcode every possible return type into an if or case statement.

I have also thought about creating an additional method that checks the class before calling the method retrieving the value and using different methods with different return types, depending on the result of that. But this seems just like the same approach, albeit implemented differently.

What would be a best practice solution to this problem?

Comment: If you have a method that returns `Object` you are doing something wrong. These should be very rare indeed.

Comment: As long as all your classes have a meaningful `toString()` use it and always return a String.

Comment: If you don't know the type of the returned value and that you cannot change the API you are actually requesting and that returns `Object`(a too wide type for a decent API that returns multiple kind of things), there is not any other solution as checking the type of the returned value as in your example.